# how to update a children component when the value of state change

Tags: reactjs

I know this question is common in react but this is a little different.

I am generating a barcode for my products dynamically by selecting my products from the dropdown like this:

[image: Example Image]

First the value of state is example but it changes with the on select event from dropdown.

When my page renders, first it generates the barcode for example but my value changed by selecting dropdown it dint generate the barcode for my next value there is code and library.

```
class QRCodePage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      productid: "exaple"
    };
  }
  setQRCode(event) {
    this.setState = {
      productid: event.target.value
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControl
          componentClass="select"
          placeholder="Select Product"
          onChange={this.setQRCode.bind(this)}
          required
        >
          <option value="">select</option>
          {this.props.products.map((product, i) =>
            <option key={i} value={product._id}>
              {product.productName}
            </option>
          )}
        </FormControl>
        <Barcode value={this.state.productid} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(event.target.value)` in the `setQRCode` ?

Comment: `this.setState` is a function, you shouldn't assign stuff to it

Comment: yes i checked it, `console.log(event.target.value)` giving the right value from the dropdown but it is not updating my state . i dont know y

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this instead. It doesn't solve this issue but it's cleaner and better code. Also try to do this and tell me what the console says.

```
class QRCodePage extends Component {
  state = {
    productid: "exaple"
  };
  setQRCode = event => {
    //Note the arrow function, which binds the function to the component.
    //This way you can use "this" in the correct scope
    this.setState(
      {
        productid: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.productid);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControl
          componentClass="select"
          placeholder="Select Product"
          onChange={this.setQRCode}
          required
        >
          <option value="">select</option>
          {this.props.products.map((product, i) =>
            <option key={i} value={product._id}>
              {product.productName}
            </option>
          )}
        </FormControl>
        <Barcode value={this.state.productid} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `onChange={this.setQRCode.bind(this)}` ?

Comment: @Andrew What do you mean?

Comment: He has binded the `setQRCode`, maybe don't correctly but this should work.

Comment: @Andrew yes it does work, but arrow functions is better style in that case. You don't want to bind this function on every call. Do it once with the arrow declaration and you are good to go

Comment: @Andrew would you be so kind to give me an upvote. I need 50 points in order to comment. Also @Fez Vrasta is right. `setState` is used wrong

Comment: not sure, why owner don't accept your answer, it should solve a problem, because the point in the wrong `setState` synaxis.

Comment: using your code i found that `console.log(event.target.value)` giving the right value from dropdown but setstate method is not updaing my productid value , i dont know why

Comment: Have you really used my code? Have you noticed the callback function within `setState`. Just console.log() your state might not work cause `setState` is asynchronous. 

You are doing this?   `this.setState(
      {
        productid: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.productid);
      }
    );`

Comment: Just for clarification. `setState` has this syntax: `this.setState({attr: newValue}, callback);` the callback function is triggered whenever `setState` is finished. So if you `console.log(this.state)` anywhere else but in the callback function of your `setState` you might get the wrong result.